# PerformException Error Performing Single Click Works with 5dp margin

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am writing the Instrumentation test and i am unable to click my view. Here's my view

```
<ConstraintLayout......>
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/go_to_next"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mobile_number_edittext"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout/>
```

My constraintLayout has 30dp margin on both left and right. My Test case is following -

```
 @Test
fun useAppContext() {
    // Context of the app under test.
    val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
    assertEquals("com.test", appContext.packageName)
    onView(withId(R.id.go_to_next)).check(matches(isDisplayingAtLeast(90)))
    onView(withId(R.id.go_to_next)).perform(click())
}
```

It fails on click() and receives an error as `Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 1457, 1213 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.test:id/go_to_next'.`

This works if I give margin to my ImageView like 5dp but it doesn't work without margin. How can I fix it? My View is completely visible in the layout, it's just it's aligned to the extreme right. FYI all animations are disabled

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the coordinates calculation may have been *broken* by `setRotation` call on the view. You could either try to rotate the file physically, or create a custom click action to force click on it instead:

```
public static ViewAction forceClick() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isClickable(), isEnabled(), isDisplayed());
        }

        @Override public String getDescription() {
            return "force click";
        }

        @Override public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            view.performClick(); // perform click without checking view coordinates.
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    };
}
```

Then use it on a button or any view that has **a click listener** attached to it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.go_to_next)).perform(forceClick());
```

Comment: You are correct. When I removed the setRotation it just worked. Glad I could know the reason

Comment: Could you share details as to how you arrived at the force click code ?

Comment: @MayuriKhinvasara I think Espresso only provides basic view actions for testings, and they often have limitations, but the good news is that we can always extend the class to do more complex testings especially with custom views or weird cases. It may not perfect but there's always a trade-off.